# Создание глобальной переменной для всех форм [C#]

Tags: c#

Знаю, что в шарпе нет по-настоящему глобальных переменных, которые работали бы между всеми формами, но как-то же можно это сделать?

Comment: ...вопрос в чем?

Answer (score 2):

Объяви статическую переменную в каком-то классе, или передавай то что тебе нужно через конструктор.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста показать пример передачи данных через конструктор?

Comment: Например есть у Вас, например, `Form1`. При нажатии на кнопку вы создаете `Form2`: `Form2 myForm = new Form2("передали строку"); myForm.Show();`. Соответственно в `Form2` должен быть соответствующий конструктор: `public Form2(string str) { //здесь делаете что-то }`

Comment: Статические переменные: `public static class MyData { public static string MyString; }` Затем, там где нужно изменяете/получаете `MyData.MyString`